# Is this the correct method of using dot product to find the angle between two vectors? C++ SFML

Tags: c++, vector, sfml, angle

So in another question I was told that you could use a simplified formula of the dot product to find the angle between two vectors:

```
angle = atan2(mouseY, mouseX) - atan2(yPos, xPos); //xPos, yPos is position of player
```

Except, from what I understood it simply takes points as vectors. Which is why the mouse and player position is plugged in the parameters. However when I move the mouse around the player in a 360 degree radius, the angle and therefore rotation of the player is a value from around -0.3... to -1.4...
Is this not the correct method? Am I supposed to be representing vectors not as X, Y positions but as something else?

There's also another formula I found which also doesn't seem to work for me:

```
angle = atan2(mouseY - yPos, mouseX - xPos);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method is correct, the second is wrong. The function `atan2(x,y)` computes the angle *in radians* of a vector pointing from `(0,0)` to `(x,y)` with respect to the x-axis. It is thus correct to calculate two angles (in radians) the vectors have wih respect to the x-axis and then subtract these from each other to obtain the angles between the two vectors.

The result of the function `atan2` is a value in the half-open interval `(-pi,pi]`. Expressed in degrees, this corresponds to `(-180°,180°)`. 0° thereby denotes a vector pointing right (along the x-axis), 90° a vector pointing up, 180° a vector pointing left and -90° a vector pointing down.

You can transform the result in radians to angles via the formula

```
atan(x,y)*180/pi
```

So, if you want to transform your resulting values into angles, just multiply them by `180/pi`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the rotation seems to be off a bit. It only really turns north east to south east if I do a full 360 rotation around the spite, and the X, Y of the sprite are centered. I'm not sure where I went wrong, but here is the code: double angle = atan2(mousey + yPos, mousex - xPos);
angle = angle * (180/3.14159);
ship.setRotation(angle);

Comment: As written in the answer, you should use your first alternative, i.e. `atan2(mouseY, mouseX) - atan2(yPos, xPos);` Further, you have to ask yourself where the origin of your coordinate system lies and appropriately shift your input. So, where on your monitor is the point (0,0)?

Comment: 0,0 is top left of the window. And I was using the first alternative, so I'm really not sure what's wrong to be honest.